# android AsyncTask share variable (global variable)

Tags: java, android, variables, android-asynctask, global

I set global variable like public static int ABC;

and execute asynctask.

Then onPostExecute assign ABC to 5. now ABC is 5.

But, UI thread have not ABC with 5, just have null variable.

how can i share global variable between asynctask and UI thread ??

my code is

```
public class ProjectInfo extends AppCompatActivity {

private Boolean isFabOpen = false; // Fab 세팅
private FloatingActionButton fab1, fab2, fab3, fab4; // fab1 -> + , fab2 -> , fab3 -> , fab4 ->
private TextView textSubjectAdd, textSubjectCorrect, textSubjectDelete;
private Animation fab_open, fab_close, rotate_forward, rotate_backward;

private Spinner ProjectSpinner;
private ArrayList<String> SpinnerList = new ArrayList<String>();
private String SubjectName = null; // 주제 추가에 쓰이는 변수
private int flagSpinner = 0; // 주체 추가 완료를 했으면 1로 되서 Spinner을 세로 set 해준다.

// DB 관련 변수 //
private static String[] listSubjectDB; // DB의 결과를 받아오는 변수
private String[] Subjecttemp; // listDB를 <br> 단위로 끊어서 받음
private String PROJ_SEQ; // 프로젝트 SEQ를 받는다.
private static ArrayAdapter<String> Subjectadapter; // 스피너 어댑터
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // 프로젝트 SEQ를 받아온다.
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    PROJ_SEQ = "PROJ_SEQ=" + intent.getStringExtra("PROJ_SEQ");
    new HttpTaskSubject().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    //Log.i("testListDB" , "value:" + listSubjectDB.length);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_projectinfo);

    // fab 관련
    textSubjectAdd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textSubjectAdd);
    textSubjectCorrect = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textSubjectCorrect);
    textSubjectDelete = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textSubjectDelete);
    fab1 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab1);
    fab2 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab2);
    fab3 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab3);
    fab4 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab4);
    fab_open = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_open);
    fab_close = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_close);
    rotate_forward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate_forward);
    rotate_backward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate_backward);
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

    // 스피너 선택 시 //
    ProjectSpinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.i("spinnervalue" , "value : " + view.getTransitionName() + " / "  + position);
        }
    });

}

public void onClickFab(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.fab1: // fab 추가 보여주기
            animateFAB();
            break;
        case R.id.fab2: // 주제 삭제
            break;
        case R.id.fab3: // 주제 수정
            break;
        case R.id.fab4: // 주제 추가 - dialog를 통해 구현
            final EditText name = new EditText(this);
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProjectInfo.this);
            alert.setView(name);
            alert.setTitle("주제 추가");
            alert.setPositiveButton("추가", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    SubjectName = name.getText().toString();
                    flagSpinner = 1;
                    SpinnerAdd(); // 주제 추가 완료 버튼을 누르면 spinner 새로 set
                }
            });

            alert.setNegativeButton("취소", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss(); // 닫기
                    flagSpinner = 0;
                }
            });

            alert.show();
            break;
    }
}

// FAB 애니메이션 효과
public void animateFAB() {
    if (isFabOpen) {
        fab1.startAnimation(rotate_backward);
        textSubjectAdd.startAnimation(fab_close);
        textSubjectCorrect.startAnimation(fab_close);
        textSubjectDelete.startAnimation(fab_close);
        fab2.startAnimation(fab_close);
        fab3.startAnimation(fab_close);
        fab4.startAnimation(fab_close);
        fab2.setClickable(false);
        fab3.setClickable(false);
        fab4.setClickable(false);
        isFabOpen = false;
        Log.d("Raj", "close");
    } else {
        fab1.startAnimation(rotate_forward);
        textSubjectAdd.startAnimation(fab_open);
        textSubjectCorrect.startAnimation(fab_open);
        textSubjectDelete.startAnimation(fab_open);
        fab2.startAnimation(fab_open);
        fab3.startAnimation(fab_open);
        fab4.startAnimation(fab_open);
        fab2.setClickable(true);
        fab3.setClickable(true);
        fab4.setClickable(true);
        isFabOpen = true;
        Log.d("Raj", "open");
    }
}

// 주제 추가 완료시 (flag == 1 이면 spinner 새로 추가 )
public void SpinnerAdd() {
    if (flagSpinner == 1) {
        SpinnerList.add(SubjectName);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, SpinnerList);
        ProjectSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        // DB에 추가된 주자를 insert 한다. //

    } else {
        return;
    }

}

/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
public Action getIndexApiAction() {
    Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
            .setName("ProjectInfo Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
            .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-URL-HERE]"))
            .build();
    return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
            .setObject(object)
            .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.connect();
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
    client.disconnect();
}

// PHP 검색 쿼리 보내는 class
public class HttpTaskSubject extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    /* Bitmap bitmap , String image는 전역변수 */
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {

            String urlPath = "http://58.142.149.131/grad/Grad_project_list_subject.php";

            // 내가 보낼 데이터 (쿼리, SUBSEQ 전역변수, switch 에서 정해준다.)
            String data = PROJ_SEQ;

            URL url = new URL(urlPath);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

            //추가 할 내용 - 서버 on/off 검사

            // 문자열 전송
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String CheckNull = "0";
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            CheckNull = sb.toString();

            if (sb.toString() != "") {
                listSubjectDB = sb.toString().split("<br>");
                return sb.toString();
            } else {
                return null;
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //오류시 null 반환
        return null;
    }

    //asyonTask 3번째 인자와 일치 매개변수값 -> doInBackground 리턴값이 전달됨
    //AsynoTask 는 preExcute - doInBackground - postExecute 순으로 자동으로 실행됩니다.
    //ui는 여기서 변경
    protected void onPostExecute(String value) { // 스피너 불러오기

        ProjectSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ProjectSpinner);
        Subjectadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, SpinnerList);
        for (int i = 1; i < listSubjectDB.length; i++) {
            Subjecttemp = split(listSubjectDB[i]); // seq / 주제 <BR>
            Subjectadapter.add(Subjecttemp[1]);
        }
        ProjectSpinner.setAdapter(Subjectadapter);
        PROJ_SEQ = null;

        super.onPostExecute(value);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}

// PHP DB insert 쿼리를 보내는 class (주제추가)
public class HttpTaskSubjectAdd extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    /* Bitmap bitmap , String image는 전역변수 */
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {

            String urlPath = "http://58.142.149.131/grad/Grad_project_list_subject.php";

            // 내가 보낼 데이터 (쿼리, SUBSEQ 전역변수, switch 에서 정해준다.)
            String data = "ADD";

            URL url = new URL(urlPath);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

            //추가 할 내용 - 서버 on/off 검사

            // 문자열 전송
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String CheckNull = "0";
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            CheckNull = sb.toString();

            if (sb.toString() != "") {
                listSubjectDB = sb.toString().split("<br>");
                return sb.toString();
            } else {
                return null;
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //오류시 null 반환
        return null;
    }

    //asyonTask 3번째 인자와 일치 매개변수값 -> doInBackground 리턴값이 전달됨
    //AsynoTask 는 preExcute - doInBackground - postExecute 순으로 자동으로 실행됩니다.
    //ui는 여기서 변경
    protected void onPostExecute(String value) { // 스피너 불러오기

        ProjectSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ProjectSpinner);
        Subjectadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, SpinnerList);
        for (int i = 1; i < listSubjectDB.length; i++) {
            Subjecttemp = split(listSubjectDB[i]); // seq / 주제 <BR>
            Subjectadapter.add(Subjecttemp[1]);
        }
        ProjectSpinner.setAdapter(Subjectadapter);
        PROJ_SEQ = null;
        super.onPostExecute(value);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}

// PHP 주제에 해당하는 파일 불러오는 통신 class
public class HttpTaskSubjectShow extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    /* Bitmap bitmap , String image는 전역변수 */
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {

            String urlPath = "http://58.142.149.131/grad/Grad_project_list_subject.php";

            // 내가 보낼 데이터 (쿼리, SUBSEQ 전역변수, switch 에서 정해준다.)
            String data = "ADD";

            URL url = new URL(urlPath);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

            //추가 할 내용 - 서버 on/off 검사

            // 문자열 전송
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String CheckNull = "0";
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            CheckNull = sb.toString();

            if (sb.toString() != "") {
                listSubjectDB = sb.toString().split("<br>");
                return sb.toString();
            } else {
                return null;
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //오류시 null 반환
        return null;
    }

    //asyonTask 3번째 인자와 일치 매개변수값 -> doInBackground 리턴값이 전달됨
    //AsynoTask 는 preExcute - doInBackground - postExecute 순으로 자동으로 실행됩니다.
    //ui는 여기서 변경
    protected void onPostExecute(String value) { // 스피너 불러오기

        ProjectSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ProjectSpinner);
        Subjectadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, SpinnerList);
        for (int i = 1; i < listSubjectDB.length; i++) {
            Subjecttemp = split(listSubjectDB[i]); // seq / 주제 <BR>
            Subjectadapter.add(Subjecttemp[1]);
        }
        ProjectSpinner.setAdapter(Subjectadapter);
        PROJ_SEQ = null;
        super.onPostExecute(value);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}

// listDB를 #단위로 끊어서 반환
public String[] split(String temp123) {
    String[] temp2 = temp123.split("#");
    return temp2;
  }
}
```

i want that ProjectSpinner work on UI thread... but null.

Comment: post your code ....

Comment: Without code it is difficult to understand what you exactly want to achieve.

Comment: @SungRyongJo please edit your question and read the help for formating the code. Don't post your code in comments.

Comment: yes. i update my code. please help me.

Comment: why are you initializing ProjectSpinner in each AsynchTask. Instead do it in oncreate of your Activity and then do what you want with it. And make sure to clear the adapter before reloading it.

Comment: yes. i initialized ProjectSpinner in onCreate(). but problem is same..

Comment: i press Log and i take a result like "on a null object reference" about ProjectSpinner. So i think, if thread work onPost~~, variable initialize automatic... then UI thread ( main thread ) dosen't recognize ProjectSpinner. So that just have null value. right?

Comment: Just a point of terminology, Java has no global variables.  That variable is a static variable, associated with the class it's declared in.

Answer (score 1):

`AsyncTask` is background process if your are doing like this

```
// background process started
new AsncTaskClass.execute();
//you are getting value from static variable,
//this line will be executed immediately after execute `AsyncTask` it will not wait while finish so you will get `null` value 
String value = AsncTaskClass.ABC;
```

for your solution you have to use abstract or interface for getting value after postExecute see Example:

> AsyncTask class

```
public abstract class DemoAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids){
        return null;
    }
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
         onGetValue(pass value here);
    }

     public abstract void onGetValue(String value);//Create an `abstract` method in AsyncTask class

    }
```

> Now call above class as you done like

```
 new DemoAsync() {
     @Override
     public void onGetValue(String value) {
            //you will get this implemented method 
            // TO do something here, hurray you got value!
     }
 }.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

HI I am posting my sample code below please read and try this.

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static String globalString;
    TextView hello;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        hello = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        new asyncclass().execute("");
    }
    private class asyncclass extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "New message for Hello word";

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            globalString = s;
            hello.setText(globalString);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i press Log and i take a result like "on a null object reference" about ProjectSpinner. So i think, if thread work onPost~~, variable initialize automatic... then UI thread ( main thread ) dosen't recognize ProjectSpinner. So that just have null value. right?